# How to the get current openMP thread pool size

Tags: openmp

Is there a way to determine at runtime what the current OpenMP thread pool size is?

By this I mean the actual number of threads that have been spawned by OpenMP and have not been reaped, not the maximum number of allowed threads (`omp_get_num_procs`) nor the number of threads that will be used by default in a new parallel region (`omp_get_num_threads`).

**Motivation:** I have a Python library that forks subprocesses for certain computations, including some that use OpenMP under the hood via extension modules.  If someone calls any OpenMP-based function before forking, the process halts.  This is because [OpenMP isn't fork-safe](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#OpenmpAndFork): a process will hang if `fork` is used "after OpenMP features are utilized."  I'd like this forking library to auto-detect if it's too late to fork because OpenMP features have already been utilized.  On such a detection, it will raise an exception instead of proceeding and hanging.  The best approach that comes to mind is to detect if the OpenMP thread pool has been launched yet, and it's not clear what the best way of doing that is.  Shelling out to `pstack` and scraping the stack traces for `libgomp.so` feels too hacky, and I don't know if it would work well for other OpenMP implementations like Intel's.

Comment: As far as I know the thread pool is whatever the number of threads is for the first parallel region that is entered. So if you set OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 then the pool will have four threads. I have seen this by checking the threads bound to the process. I think if you use a larger number of threads later then it expands the pool and if you go back to a smaller number of threads for another parallel region then the other threads idle. You could write some code to test this. Threads pools are not in the standard so could be implemented differently in GCC, ICC, and MSVC.

Comment: I asked a similar question [thread-pools-with-openmp-overhead-and-changing-the-number-of-threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424359/thread-pools-with-openmp-overhead-and-changing-the-number-of-threads).  See Hristo Iliev's comment "libgomp spawns additional threads when more are needed but does not kill already spawned ones and rather puts them to sleep in a docking barrier. The actual overhead could be measured using EPCC's OpenMP microbenchmarks."

Comment: Thanks for part of the answer.  To be clear, I'm mostly interested in knowing whether the actual pool size is 0 vs. >0.  If the actual pool size is 0, it's safe to fork, not exec, and then use OpenMP in the forked process, regardless of `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.  If it's >0 in a process, it's not safe to use OpenMP in a forked but not exec-ed subprocess.